# AttributeError when using django-datatrans and django-markitup together

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use [django-datatrans](https://github.com/citylive/django-datatrans) to translate a `MarkupField` (from [django-markitup](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-markitup/overview)) on a model. Both apps work correctly independently, but when I register datatrans to translate a `MarkupField` then I can't add objects in the admin anymore.

Relevant code:

```
from django.db import models
from markitup.fields import MarkupField
from datatrans.utils import register

class Work(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = MarkupField(help_text=MARKDOWN_HELP)

class WorkTranslation(object):
    fields = ('title', 'content')

register(Work, WorkTranslation)
```

When I try to add a new Work-object in the admin I get the following error:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

The error happens here, in the markitup-module (in the line `rendered = render_func(value.raw)`:

```
.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/markitup/fields.py in pre_save

def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    value = super(MarkupField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
    rendered = render_func(value.raw)
    setattr(model_instance, _rendered_field_name(self.attname), rendered)
    return value.raw
```

Local vars when failing:

```
add: False
model_instance: <Work: This is the title>
value: u'This is the content.'
self: <markitup.fields.MarkupField: content>
```

I have tried to inspect the variable `value` when the `Work` class is not registered for translation. In that case (and then it does work correctly) it is not a unicode string but an instance of `markitup.fields.Markup`.

I have not been able to figure out why the type changes and I realize this question is pretty specific. But I hope someone has insights anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) and django-markitup when testing it:

```
class ModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_my_class(self):
        self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, models.MyClass.objects.create)
```

It works for me with:

```
class ModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_my_class(self):
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            models.MyClass.objects.create(info='', info_de='')
```

Where my installed languages are `en` and `de`. My default language is `en`. `info` is my field with markitup and translation. (I'm testing here that a field is required on `MyClass`, therefore the `IntegrityError`.)

(Btw. this produces a slightly different error:

```
class ModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_my_class(self):
        self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, models.MyClass.objects.create(info=''))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'raw'
```

)

Maybe this helps someone.